# Google APPS Script Email Notification

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am new to google apps script need help. I need a Google Sheet to email different users when a change has been made to a column, like a work flow.

When anything in column A is updated it emails a specific user that user then updates column B and so forth. I found this code but it does not work, it just sends emails when any change has been made. Please can anyone help?

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "kjc@stahs.org.uk";
  var message = '';
  if(cell.indexOf('K')!=-1){ 
    message = sheet.getRange('K'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  }
  var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
  var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: «' + row + '». New comment: «' + cellvalue + '». For message: «' + message + '»';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
};
```